# Prove that $f(x)= \int_{0}^\infty\sin t \cdot x(t)dt$, is linear and continuous and find $\Vert f \Vert$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $a>0$, we denote $X$ is a space of real function $x=x(t)$ continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and satisfy $\sup e^{at} \vert x(t) \vert <\infty$.

On $X$, we define $\Vert x \Vert =\displaystyle \sup_{0 \le t < +\infty} e^{at}\vert x(t) \vert $.

Prove that $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^\infty\sin t \cdot x(t)dt$, $x \in X$ is linear and continuous and find $\Vert f \Vert$.

I proved $f$ is linear already and when it comes to "continuous" I have tried to prove $\vert f(x) \vert \le M \Vert x \Vert$ but have no idea.

Any hint or solution is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:hilbert-spaces]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I edited tags, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $|f(x)|=|\int_0^{\infty} e^{-at} \sin t \, e^{at}x(t)dt| \leq \|x\| \int _0^{\infty} e^{-at} |\sin t|dt$. If $x(t)=e^{-at} \text{sgn} (\sin t)$ then $\|x\|=1$ and  $f(x)= \int _0^{\infty} e^{-at} |\sin t|dt$. This would have proved that $\|f\| =\int _0^{\infty} e^{-at} |\sin t|dt$ but for the fact that $x$ is not continuous. You know exactly where $\sin t$ changes sign so modify $x$ suitably near those points to show that $\|f\| =\int _0^{\infty} e^{-at} |\sin t|dt$

Comment: $|\sin t | \leq 1$ and $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-at}dt=\frac 1  a$. @NguyenThy

Comment: Can I take a sequence $x_n$  and $\lim x_n(t)=x(t)$ ? I have thought this idea but stuck to choose $x_n$

Comment: @NguyenThy You need continuous functions $x_n$ such that $\int |x(t)-x_n(t)|dt  \to 0$.

Comment: Can I choose $x_n(t)=e^{-at}\max \{-1,\min\{1,n \ \sin t\}\}$?

Comment: @NguyenThy Yes, that is neat!